# How can I automatically dismiss my Dialog Box based on some condition in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog

I am checking whether a user is connected to the internet or not using the connectivity_plus package. I have used a listener to check whether the internet status changes and that works perfectly fine. Now, when the user is not connected to the internet I want to display some Dialog Box and then when internet is back on I want the Dialog Box to disappear automatically. I have searched for a similar issue but have found none.

Here is the code:
**Sample Widget:**

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print, use_build_context_synchronously

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:providers_sample/widgets/internet_dialog.dart';
import 'package:providers_sample/widgets/second_widget.dart';
import 'package:providers_sample/widgets/test_dialog.dart';

import '../providers/InternetStatusProvider.dart';

class SampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  late StreamSubscription subscription;
  String internetCnnectivity = "";
  SampleWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  void internetConnectionStatus(BuildContext context) async {
    InternetStatusProvider internetStatusProvider =
        Provider.of<InternetStatusProvider>(context, listen: false);

    ConnectivityResult connectionStatus =
        await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    updateConnectionStatus(context, connectionStatus, internetStatusProvider);
    subscription =
        Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((connectionStatusListener) {
      updateConnectionStatus(
          context, connectionStatusListener, internetStatusProvider);
    });
    print("Internet Status: ${internetStatusProvider.internetStatus}");
  }

  updateConnectionStatus(
      BuildContext context,
      ConnectivityResult connectionStatusResult,
      InternetStatusProvider internetStatusProvider) async {
    if (connectionStatusResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
        connectionStatusResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      internetStatusProvider.setInternetStatus(true);
    } else {
      internetConnectivityAlertDialog(context);
      internetStatusProvider.setInternetStatus(false);
    }
  }

  void dispose() {
    subscription.cancel;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    internetConnectionStatus(context);
    return SecondWidget();
  }
}
```

**No Internet Dialog Box:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void internetConnectivityAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
      title: Text(
        "Attention",
        style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
      ),
      content: Text("No internet."),
    ),
  );
}
```

**Internet Status Provider:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InternetStatusProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  late bool _internetConnected;

  bool get internetStatus {
    return _internetConnected;
  }

  void setInternetStatus(bool internetStatus) {
    if (_internetConnected != internetStatus) {
      this._internetConnected = internetStatus;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are using Getx, you may just try Get.back() or if you are not using it, try Navigator.pop(context) when user is online. That should close the dialog box.

Comment: Navigator.pop(context) does not work, I already tried that approach. I just added that line in my if block where I pass 'true' to my provider. If you are very confident that this should work then could you please show me how to do it, I may be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still need help with this?
Try

Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();

see if that helps

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33701576)